# Possibility of using hash as key in redis

Tags: ruby, redis

In Python:

```
import redis
db = redis.StrictRedis()
db.set({'test1': 'a', 'test2' : 'b'},1)
print db.get({'test2': 'b', 'test1' : 'a'})
result : 1
```

How can I do it in Ruby? (I don't want to use JSON because in JSON, order of the elements in a hash must be strong.)

Answer (score 0):

It may be possible, but not straight ahead as it is in Python. That's because the key will be converted in String, but there will not be any kind of specific normalization. Therefore, if you swap the position of the keys, the string representation will change.

```
2.1.5 :001 > r = Redis.current
 => #<Redis client v3.2.1 for redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0>
2.1.5 :002 > r.set({test1: 'a', test2: 'b'}, 1)
 => "OK"
2.1.5 :003 > r.keys
 => ["{:test1=>\"a\", :test2=>\"b\"}"]
2.1.5 :004 > r.get({test2: 'b', test1: 'a'})
 => nil
```

Moreover, in Ruby Hash can be mapped with keys as String or Symbol, which returns different to_s representations.

What you need to do, if you want to use the Hash as symbol, is to apply a normalization function to it first. For instance:

```
def to_key(hash)
  hash.to_a.sort.map { |pair| "%s:%s" % pair }.join("/")
end
```

That will convert

```
{test2: 'b', test1: 'a'}
{test1: 'a', test2: 'b'}
{"test1" => 'a', "test2" => 'b'}
...
```

into

```
"test1:a/test2:b"
```

that can be effectively used as key.